# how to convert json to string with out cases changing to upper in java:android?

Tags: java, json, case-sensitive

I have a Json object like this

```
{"action":"user.password.reset","username":"09119503191"}
```

And it is made with this code:

```
finalJson.put(publicClass.action, publicClass.passwordReset);
```

But the problem is when is convert it `toString`:

```
finalJson.toString()
```

All cases change to upper case.

can any body help me why this happens and how to refuse it?